# How can I return hyperlinked text in a Lexresponse?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, chatbot, amazon-lex

So I am building a lex chatbot and I am trying to return a response with hyperlinked text. I have the chatbot sitting on a front end but I cant seem to find a way to return responses with hyperlinks. Heres what I have so far

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NijBT.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/m16oT.jpg

Now Ive read that the responses from lex are formatted to where the chatbot is sitting. For example, in the chatbot test window on the Amazon site, returning  hyperlinks is impossible, but skype automatically hyperlinks URLs. But I have mine sitting on a browser but I still cant get a hyperlinked response in the bot.

Would love if anyone could help me out! Thanks in advance!

Comment: This isn't about Lex, it's about your browser chat. So if you have a custom browser chat window (using JavaScript?), then you should format this question for how to display the hyperlink properly through that and include the chat's code.

Answer (score 1):

The test console window of Lex does not support html rendering. You can instead deploy your chatbot to a channel like facebook or slack, and it will be rendered correctly.

You can use the custom markup option to send a response in the following json format to format it by your client.

```
{
    "text": "Check out the following link",
    "type":"hyperlink",
    "links":[{
        "linkText":"Google",
        "url":"https://google.com"
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lex can return any response that you want, but it's the responsibility of chat client to parse that response and show accordingly.
So you need to write your logic to parse hyperlink and show them.

In your case you can send response from Lex like : `Please visit [link]www.google.com[\link]`.
Then you can write your logic to show the text in `anchor tag <a>` in your chat window so that it is parsed as hyperlink.

Hope it helps.